# @Font-Face with condensed fonts in the same family

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a number of fonts which fall under the same font family name. I need to generate the @font-face for these fonts

```
Family Name: Test Pro
Font Name: TestPro-Cond
Font Name: TestPro-CondIt
Font Name: TestPro-It
```

I understand I can create a @font-face with whatever name I want and reference the font files. However I would like to follow the correct web standard. What I am unsure about is how to handle these 'condensed' fonts. Does anyone have experience with this?

Currently I have

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro Bold Condensed Italic";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-BoldCondIt.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro Bold Italic";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-BoldIt.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but google fonts @import does it like this:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100italic,300,500);`

Answer (score 3):

Condensed fonts actually are basically a different family, if you think about it.

What you're doing is fine, but you can simplify the whole tree like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro Condensed";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-CondReg.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro Condensed";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-BoldCondIt.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-Reg.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Test Pro";
    src: url('./fonts/TestPro-BoldIt.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

And then only worry about using `font-family: "Test Pro";` etc in your styles with the appropriate `font-weight` and `font-style` to trigger the heavier weight and/or italic version. The browser will automatically simulate any combinations you don't include (though it may look bad.)

Last thing, try to use `woff` and `woff2` for the `src` if possible, the file size is much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using the css property called `font-stretch`, but at the time of writing it's not covered in all major browsers.

See https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-font-stretch